# How to vectorize this ifelse statement?

Tags: r

I have the following ifelse statement where $TotalReplacementRatio is a column with numbers from 0-1.5. It's dragging my for loop, so I want to vectorize it.

```
 ModelOutputTRA$RetirementReady <- ifelse(ModelOutputTRA$TotalReplacementRatio > RetReadiness,"Yes","Not")
```

I tried the following alternative to make it run faster in a loop, but I get an error:

```
rrv1 <- ModelOutputTRA$TotalReplacementRatio >= RetReadiness 
rrv2 <- ModelOutputTRA$TotalReplacementRatio < 0 
  
ModelOutputTRA$RetirementReady[rrv1] <- "Yes"
ModelOutputTRA$RetirementReady[rrv2] <- "Not"
```

The rrv1 obviously creates a logical vector, which I want to use to filter the column and insert the factor levels shown. Is that possible?

I will end up repeating this process for another ifelse inside my for loop:

```
ModelOutputTRA$SSLevel <- ifelse(ModelOutputTRA$FinalSalary >= ModelOutputTRA$FinalSSHigh,"High",ifelse(ModelOutputTRA$FinalSalary >= ModelOutputTRA$FinalSSLow,"Mid","Low"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to vectorize, convert the logical vector to numeric index (in `R`, indexing starts from 1, so TRUE/FALSE -> 1/0, added 1 -> 2/1) and this can be used to replace a vector based on the position

```
c("Not", "Yes")[1 + (ModelOutputTRA$TotalReplacementRatio > RetReadiness)]
```

---

For multiple comparisons, use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
with(ModelOutputTRA, case_when(SSLevel >= FinalSSHigh ~ "High",
   FinalSalary >= FinalSSLow ~ "Mid",
   TRUE ~ "Low"))
```

Comment: I unfortunately don't have the reputation necessary to mark this as correct, but it worked beautifully and significantly sped up my code.